# why does this throw indentation error?

Tags: python, indentation

```
for bucketLabel, eventList in test_source_json.iteritems(): 
    if bucketLabel == "spotlight": 
        for event in eventList: 
            try: 
                for key in source_keys: 
                    if key not in event: 
                        if key not in responseDictionary[currentTestName][url]: 
                            responseDictionary[currentTestName][url][key] = list()
                        responseDictionary[currentTestName][url][key].append(event)
            except: 
                exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                logging.info("caught exception %s, and obj %s at line number %s" % (exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb.tb_lineno))
                continue
```

This code throws an indentation error at line 4 `try:`
http://repl.it/N7W illustrates the error

Totally confused as to why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're using tabs instead of spaces on that line

Comment: uh.  what's the difference?  and how do you know when to use which?  (forgive me...still fairly new to python)

Comment: in python, there is a difference, you shouldnt mix tabs and spaces anyways in any language

Comment: you should pick one or the other, and always use it

Comment: 4 spaces is 4 spaces. Tabs are a special indent character (represented in some environments as `\t`). They're different ASCII codes, and mixing them is ambiguous. The width of a tab could be changed in your environment, and that could change where that line indents. That's why it's a Syntax Error

Comment: @Brad You should either use one or the other in python. The [PEP 8 Style Guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests four spaces for each indentation.

Comment: No they aren't. Try selecting text in the middle of the tab. Most lines allow it. Line 4 does not. Line 4 is the only line with tabs.

Comment: @Brad: No they're not. Assuming your question is copied and pasted correctly, the `for` line has two tabs; the `try` line has 12 spaces. In your editor, and on SO, the two tabs looks like 8 spaces (less indented than the next line), but to Python (and maybe in a different editor) the two tabs look like 16 spaces (more indented), hence the error.

Comment: @mhlester: You've got it backward. Lines 2 and 3 have tabs; line 4 does not.

Comment: crazy.   trying it now

Comment: @CameronSparr I know what you're saying, but I thought I'd point out that make mixes tabs and spaces, and you really don't have a choice about it. :-(

Comment: what a beat down.  Thanks.  I tend to always use tabs and must have unconsciously used spaces there and not realized it.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The problem—as it often is in cases like this—is that you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Lines 2 and 3 are indented with tabs; line 3 starts with two tab characters. That presumably looks like 8 spaces in your text editor, but as far as Python is concerned, it's 16 spaces.

Line 4 is indented with 12 spaces. So, in your editor, it looks more indented than line 3. But to Python, it's *less* indented. Hence the error.

The solution is to always use spaces, never tabs. (Alternatively, you can always use tabs instead, just so long as you don't mix them… but always spaces is easier and better in many ways.)

Most editors can be configured to do this—and to show tabs distinctly differently from spaces. The ones that can't (like Notepad) probably shouldn't be used for programming.

You should also run Python with the [`-t` or `-tt`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t) flag to diagnose `IndentationError`s, because it will tell you that you're using tabs and spaces inconsistently. The [`tabnanny`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tabnanny.html) module/script can also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Python requires that you use either tabs or spaces for indentation and not both.  The official Python recommendation is to use four spaces rather than a tab, but what's more important is you must use the same on each line.

Comment: StackOverflow auto-corrects it.  You can see the problem in the link he provided.

Comment: SO only auto-corrects it in the fancy display; if you click the `edit` link for the question (you can always discard your edit), you can copy his original code directly, or just mouse or key around within it. This can be helpful for diagnosing tab errors in pasted code.